# Assign weights from keras to torch model

Tags: keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I am making a project for checking if anime faces is similar or not. I tried training a model by myself, but it doesn't make significant progress. So I decided to take already trained model and tune it to my needs. I found [this model](https://github.com/abars/AnimeFaceClassifier/) on github.

The model structure is:

```
N_CATEGORIES = 203
IMAGE_SIZE = 224

input_tensor = Input(shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3))
base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,input_tensor=input_tensor)
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(N_CATEGORIES, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

for layer in base_model.layers[:15]:
   layer.trainable = False
```

Keras model summary:

```
Model: "model_1"
Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param  
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
                                                                 
 block1_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
                                                                 
 block1_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
                                                                 
 block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
                                                                 
 block2_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
                                                                 
 block2_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
                                                                 
 block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 block3_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
                                                                 
 block3_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 block3_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
                                                                 
 block4_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
                                                                 
 block4_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block4_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
                                                                 
 block5_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
                                                                 
 global_average_pooling2d_1  (None, 512)               0         
  (GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                       
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1024)              525312    
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 203)               208075    
                                                                 
=================================================================
```

I downloaded an .hdf5 file for this model. By I can't convert it to .pt format. I made similar to vgg16 structure in torch:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class CustomModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__()

        self.block1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        )

        self.block2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        )

        self.block3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        )

        self.block4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        )

        self.block5 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        )

        self.global_avg_pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, 1))

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(512, 1024)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 203)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.block1(x)
        x = self.block2(x)
        x = self.block3(x)
        x = self.block4(x)
        x = self.block5(x)
        x = self.global_avg_pool(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

pytorch_model = CustomModel()
```

I imported weight to keras:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('animeface_vgg16.hdf5')
weights=model.get_weights()
```

Tried to follow method like in [this code example](https://github.com/gereshes/Blog-Companion/blob/master/keras2PyTorch-Hard/createKears.py). I understand how to assing keras weights to fc layers. But there wasn't any example with convolutional layers.

I found only examples of building model structure in other questions on stack overflow, but nobody showed how to assign weights to it.

Please explain me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A easy way to do it is to convert the model directly from keras to pytorch using onnx as the intermediate model. This can be easily done in a couple of steps:

Step 1: Save Keras model as ONNX

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model
import onnx
import keras2onnx

onnx_model_name = 'baselineonnxmodel.onnx'

model = load_model('baselinekerasmodel.h5')
onnx_model = keras2onnx.convert_keras(model, model.name)
onnx.save_model(onnx_model, onnx_model_name)
```

Step 2: Load ONNX model and convert to pytorch. Install onnx2pytorch using `pip install onnx2pytorch`

```py
import onnx
from onnx2pytorch import ConvertModel

onnx_model = onnx.load('baselineonnxmodel.onnx')
pytorch_model = ConvertModel(onnx_model)
```

You can now use the `pytorch_model` for making predictions.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer by myself. Here is a model structure:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class CustomModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_categories):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__()

        self.block1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        )

        self.block2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        )

        self.block3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        )

        self.block4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        )

        self.block5 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, 1))
        )

        self.dense = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(512, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(1024, n_categories),
            nn.Softmax(dim=0)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.block1(x)
        x = self.block2(x)
        x = self.block3(x)
        x = self.block4(x)
        x = self.block5(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        return x

N_CATEGORIES  = 203
pytorch_model = CustomModel(N_CATEGORIES)
```

It's a loading of weights:

```
pytorch_model.block1[0].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(weights[0]))
pytorch_model.block1[0].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[1])
pytorch_model.block1[2].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(weights[2]))
pytorch_model.block1[2].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[3])

pytorch_model.block2[0].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(weights[4]))
pytorch_model.block2[0].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[5])
pytorch_model.block2[2].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(weights[6]))
pytorch_model.block2[2].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[7])

pytorch_model.block3[0].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(weights[8]))
pytorch_model.block3[0].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[9])
pytorch_model.block3[2].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(weights[10]))
pytorch_model.block3[2].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[11])
pytorch_model.block3[4].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(weights[12]))
pytorch_model.block3[4].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[13])

pytorch_model.block4[0].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(weights[14]))
pytorch_model.block4[0].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[15])
pytorch_model.block4[2].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(weights[16]))
pytorch_model.block4[2].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[17])
pytorch_model.block4[4].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(weights[18]))
pytorch_model.block4[4].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[19])

pytorch_model.block5[0].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(weights[20]))
pytorch_model.block5[0].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[21])
pytorch_model.block5[2].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(weights[22]))
pytorch_model.block5[2].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[23])
pytorch_model.block5[4].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(weights[24]))
pytorch_model.block5[4].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[25])

pytorch_model.dense[0].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(weights[26]))
pytorch_model.dense[0].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[27])

pytorch_model.dense[2].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(np.transpose(weights[28]))
pytorch_model.dense[2].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(weights[29])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).