# How do I convert CNN from tensorflow to Pytorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

[Tensorflow code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0lgy.png)
[pytorch Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqGgs.png)
I have converted the Tensorflow model to PyTorch. However, I've observed some discrepancies in performance, particularly in detecting the minor class. Even though I used the same preprocessing file for both models, the TensorFlow model still outperforms the PyTorch one. To make my point clear, I am sharing screenshots of both. Can someone please guide me if I misinterpreted something in the Pytorch version? In Pytorch, instead of BCE loss function, I used BCEWithLogitsLoss. I want to achieve similar results.

I was expecting the same result, but the result from TensorFlow is better, and PyTorch results are far low, especially the RECALL AND TPR.

Comment: Hey I would suggest you try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76808820/13201464

Comment: Kindly check both Tensor flow and PyTorch are running on the same hardware with similar software configurations. Please add some logging statements in your code so that we can track the metrics, loss and model predictions during training and evaluation. and check the evaluation metrics eg., precision, recall and TPR are computed in both the Tensor flow and PyTorch.
Please refer this [link](https://saturncloud.io/blog/converting-tensorflow-model-to-pytorch-model/#step-by-step-converting-tensorflow-model-to-pytorch-model) to convert CNN from Tensor flow model to PyTorch model.